# Change send_mail() method to EmailMessage - Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to change a `send_mail()` method into an `EmailMessage` one in Django 1.6.

This is how my method looks with `send_mail()`

```
 # Send email
        if user_profile.contracting:
            subject = _('Your question on project {} has been answered')
            body = _('You can read your answer here {}')
            email = question.user.email

        else:
            subject = _('Your have a new question on project {}')
            body = _('You can read your question here: {}')
            email = project.user.email

        send_mail(subject.format(project.name),
                  body.format(
                      os.environ.get('CURRENT_URL') + '/' +
                      reverse('projects_id', args=(project.id,))[1:]),
                  'no-responder@contratlos.com', [email])

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projects_id',
                                            args=(project.id,)))
```

Now, trying to change it, it doesn't throw any error but doesn't sends any email:

```
 # Send email
        if user_profile.contracting:
            subject = _('Your question on project {} has been answered')
            body = _('You can read your answer here {}')
            email = question.user.email

        else:
            subject = _('Your have a new question on project {}')
            body = _('You can read your question here: {}')
            email = project.user.email

        correo = EmailMessage(subject.format(project.name),
                  body.format(
                      os.environ.get('CURRENT_URL') + '/' +
                      reverse('projects_id', args=(project.id,))[1:]),
                  'no-responder@contratlos.com', [email],['kristian.koci@gmail.com'])

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projects_id',
                                            args=(project.id,)))
```

Is there something am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmailMessage` is a convenience class for creating customized email messages. However, unlike `send_mail()`, you need to explicitly call [`.send()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage) in order to actually send the message:

```
correo.send()
```